# Angular compiler-cli & webpack: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to restart an older project of mine and am running into some JS spaghetti. I'd be extremely grateful if someone could give me some clues as to which package broke what. Upon running `npm run build` I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (native)
    at __extends (C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\expression_diagnostics.js:14:9)
    at C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\packages\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\expression_diagnostics.ts:186:44
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\packages\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\expression_diagnostics.ts:186:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\packages\compiler-cli\index.ts:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Symbol.Symbol._symbol._program (C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\node_modules\ngast\ngast.bundle.js:2:138)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gmerc\Documents\GitHub\clt\CLT-webapp\frontend\node_modules\ngast\ngast.bundle.js:5:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Here's what my `polyfills.ts` file looks like:

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');

import 'ts-helpers';

if (process.env.ENV === 'build') {
  // Production

} else {
  // Development

  Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;

  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

This code all worked perfect some 1-2 months ago, but now something seems to be causing a break. Any ideas? Here's my package.json for reference as well:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "karma start",
    "posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
    "test-watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.10.1",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "auth0-lock": "^10.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.39",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.46",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.58",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.11",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "3.0.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.9.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using and what OS? We have a similar problem and I'm trying to formulate a hypothesis...

Comment: @BenjaminSeiller I was attempting to compile my code on Windows 10, node V6.11.2 LTS I believe. My laptop hasn't updated it's packages yet and can still compile my code, so when I get home today I think i'll list out what package versions are installed on my laptop and compile it to my desktop

Comment: Our project just works find under Windows 8, node 6.9.4, but with macOs v?, node 7.x it throws exactly the error you described during the page load while doing `ng serve`. This kind of error popped up some weeks ago in the issues of angular related projects on github - if your interested I can share our findings so far - currently we suspect webpack to be the culprit or at least an accomplice in what is happening as the content of the stacktraces list totally unrelated classes...